# Division algorithm related question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading a textbook.
Under the chapter division algorithm, which talks about quotient, dividend and divisors. 
There is one exercise question

What can be deduced about nonzero integers $a$ and $b$ if $a\not\mid b$ and $b\not \mid a$?

Any idea?

Comment: Well, what do you think?  What can be deduced about 4 and 7?  About 12 and 16? That can't be said about 15 and 30.  There's lots of things.  Prime factors and gcd or things I'd look into.  Although since it's the division algorithm, I suspect it's the gcd that will be useful.

Comment: Are you sure the question isn't, what can be deduced if $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $a$?

Comment: @user35508 No you can't.  gcd(4,6)=2.

Comment: @user35508 Not necessarily, If the $gcd(a,b)=1$ that implies that $a $ and $b$ are coprime.  Counter example:  let $a= 24$ and $b=18$. Note that $a \nmid b$ and $b\nmid a$ however there exists a $c=3$ such that $c|b$ and $c|a$.

Answer (score 0):

Now fleablood is right there are many thing you can say, and that it depends on what you have learned.  It would be helpful if we knew the name of the book you're reading. That might help us know more about the writers Question.  With that said think about the equation $d=xa+by$ such that $d,x,y \in \mathbb Z$. If $a \nmid b$ and $b \nmid a$, what can you say about $d$? Is there something that can be said about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Thank you very much. The book is just a photocopied version of one portion of the original book, which is used for Further Mathematics SL topic 5 or HL topic 11 of IB programme. I do not have the original book. So I don't know the title or publisher of this book. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: @user418166 Well if that's the case then one thing you know for sure is $a \neq b$. Also, $a/b, b/a \in \mathbb Z$. If $a$ or $b$ is prime then the $gcd(a,b)=1$ e.g. they are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can be deduced, e.g. $a\neq 1$, $(a,b)\neq a,\ldots$ and so on. I would imagine that the question is preceded by a statement that something *can* be deduced under different conditions on $a$ and $b$ which would give a clue to what the author intended.